# USC does not include fresh apps

Tags: software-center

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit and I have a problem with Ubuntu software center; basically it fails to find new apps. For example I read an article on omgubuntu.co.uk such as "... was added to USC" and try to find it. But I cannot find it. Lightread, fogger, stormcloud etc.

Additional notes: That is not about updating or ubuntu 13.04 being in process. I have been using Ubuntu for a very long time and that was always the problem.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 has yet to be released, and as such, is off-topic for this site (see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)). Thanks for helping to test beta versions of Ubuntu, though!

Answer (score 2):

The "for sale" apps whether proprietary or open source, are only published for 'released' versions of Ubuntu. As 13.04 is still in development, and not yet released, these apps won't be published for 13.04, until it is released.

Comment: Fogger and lightread are free apps.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the price is 0 or 100, or if it's proprietary or open source. If it's distributed via the method of for pay applications, they are only distributed for certain stable release versions of Ubuntu, which 13.04 is not.

Answer (score -1):

You're using the Raring Ringtail (13.04) repositories, where a few apps are published. Try to add the Quantal Quetzal (12.10) repos to get full access to the Ubuntu software. Get the 12.10 repos doing this steps:

1. Open [this website](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and fill all the fields (but not 3rd Parties Repos!)
2. Open a terminal and run `cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/sources_old.list && sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`, type your password.
3. Now copy the 1st text box generated by the mentioned website.
4. Finally replace all the content at the Gedit window with the copied text.

Comment: Wow, people is really quick to do -1 without checking if it works!!!

Comment: This is about the "for sale" apps in software-center, which are not found via the standard apt sources.

Comment: Are you sure? Anyway there's Ubuntu Partner and Extras repos...

Comment: Yes, and partner and extras are something different.

Comment: @espectalll123 yes see the examples posted: Lightread, fogger, stormcloud

Comment: I've already seen, that's why I was doubting...

Comment: Not working. I still cannot find those apps.